# How can I change an input for a label without an error in value in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I tried to change the input for a label but it generates an error in value

This is my code

This is html

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-6 columns">
    <label>Edad</label>
  </div>
  <div class="small-2 columns">
    <input readonly type="text" [value]="CalculateAge()">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how you changed by the seal as it should be?

```html
<div class="small-6 columns">
  <label readonly for="text" [value]="CalculateAge()">
        </label>
</div>
```

This is component

```js
export class DatosPersonalesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  datosDTO: DatosDTO;

  public age: number;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.datosDTO = new DatosDTO();
  }
  CalculateAge(): void {
    if (this.datosDTO.datosPersonales.fechaNacimiento) {
      var timeDiff = Math.abs(Date.now() - this.datosDTO.datosPersonales.fechaNacimiento);
      this.age = Math.ceil((timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) / 365);
    }
  }
}
```

This is error
[image]

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: I updated the question and appended the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) is typically used with the `for` attribute like so

```
<label for="age">{{ age }}</label>
<input type="text" id="age">
```

The value should be between the tags, not in the `value` property

```
get age(){
    if (this.datosDTO.datosPersonales.fechaNacimiento) {
      var timeDiff = Math.abs(Date.now() - this.datosDTO.datosPersonales.fechaNacimiento);
      return Math.ceil((timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) / 365);
    }
  }
```

---

Your functions inside class should typically not be capitalized

```
calculateAge()
```

---

You are specifying `datosDTO` as `@Input()` yet you initialize it in `ngOnInit()`. You shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call the CalculateAge function in the template, where you should just be referencing the age variable.  Also, you have declared CalculateAge to have a void return type, so even if that would work it would still return nothing into the template.

When you call CalculateAge() inside your onInit and it will load the value into the age variable which will then be loaded into your template.

Finally, to solve the actual error you'll need to pass the variable inside the label tag rather than setting the value property of the tag:

```
<div class="small-6 columns">
  <label readonly for="text">{{age}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I have done what you tell me but the error that I have attached in the question continues to appear

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that as I was focused on the first part of the problem :)  Edited solution.